# Android notification not showing more than 3 actions

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to display a notification with 5 actions, but it ony displays 3 of them. This is the code I'm using for displaying it

```
Notification notification =
            new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!")
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.action1, null, pendingIntent1).build())
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.action2, null, pendingIntent2).build())
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.action3, null, pendingIntent3).build())
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.action4, null, pendingIntent4).build())
                    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.action5, null, pendingIntent5).build())
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(MEETING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 11):

you can only show max 3 actions as mentioned in the [`Notification.Builder addAction (Notification.Action action)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(android.app.Notification.Action)) too

> A notification in its expanded form can display up to 3 actions, from
>   left to right in the order they were added.

Alternatively you create custom [`RemoteViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) and use [`setCustomContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews))

Reference

[Read Custom Notification Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

[Adding button action in custom notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification)

Answer (score 3):

Notifications can only display 3 actions.

> A notification in its expanded form can display up to 3 actions, from
>   left to right in the order they were added.

Source, the offical Notification.Builder documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(android.app.Notification.Action)

If you absolutely need more than 3 actions, you'll have to opt for a solution using a custom view to display in the notification.