# Android Interactive Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, interactive

I want to create interactive notifications for my android app like the ones in iOS: https://news.dueapp.com/ios-10-notifications-one-step-forward-one-step-back-fe712469184e. I know that android launched the interactive notification feature from Jellybean(4.1)

My question is: how many actions can I define in an interactive notifications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Android notification not showing more than 3 actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534165/android-notification-not-showing-more-than-3-actions) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

You cannot add more than 3 actions, if you want to do something like iOS, you will have to do your own notification layout, or you can also add 1 action that opens a dialog with options.